# Make new instance of the template class of a c++ object

Tags: c++, templates, metadata

So if I have

```
template <class T>
class Object {
// stuff
};
```

and I receive an instance of object in a function I want to call the constructor of class T.

```
void foo(Object object) {
 auto newT = object::T();
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically the best solution is to template the inner type:

```
template <class T>
void foo(Object<T> object) {
    T newT;
}
```

However, sometimes (with more meta-programming) this sort of solution will be more verbose than the alternatives:

---

Option 1: store the template variable in the `Object` class:

```
template <class T>
class Object {
    // stuff
public:
    using inner_type = T;
};
```

Then you can access the template type like so:

```
template <class Obj>
void foo(Obj object) {
    typename Obj::inner_type newT;
}
```

---

Option 2: make a type trait (no need to add `inner_type` to `Object`):

```
template <class T>
struct tag {
    using type = T;
};

template <class>
struct inner;

template <template <class> class S, class T>
struct inner <S<T>> : tag<T> {};

template <typename T>
using inner_t = typename inner<T>::type;
```

Which you can then use like so:

```
template <class Obj>
void foo(Obj object) {
    inner_t<Obj> newT;
}
```

---

It's probably best to generalise `inner_type` to take the first inner argument so that it could handle template types with more arguments, like `std::vector` (second argument has a default):

```
template <class>
struct front;

template <template <class, class...> class R, class S, class ... Ts>
struct front <R<S, Ts...>> : tag<S> {};

template <typename T>
using front_t = typename front<T>::type;
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/nxWbc87c1)

Comment: thanks this solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

No, you create an instance of a class template by specializing the template.  You do this by putting the type you want to use in angle brackets:

```
void foo(Object<int> object) {
    //  auto newobj = Object<int>(); this will work
    Object<int> newobj;               // but this has less cruft
}
```

or

```
template <class U>
void foo(Object<U> object) {
    //  auto newobj = Object<U>();
    Object<U> newobj  {object};
}
```

Remember that the symbol `T` does not exist outside the template definition. To get a "real" `Object` you have to put in an actual type. I chose  `int` but you will probably use something else.

Of course, this will only work if the `stuff` contains a corresponding constructor:

```
template <class T>
class Object {
   // stuff
   public:
     Object(); // often implicit but sometimes not
     Object(Object<T> const &i) = default;
   // more stuff
};
```